# The resource was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, spotify

I am getting the error when I press the request authorisation button `The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:5000/public/javascript/Login.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).` on console. There is also a second error on console which is `Uncaught ReferenceError: requestAuthorization is not defined onclick http://127.0.0.1:5000/:1           12 127.0.0.1:5000:1:1 onclick http://127.0.0.1:5000/:1`

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/global.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/loginPage.css">
        <script src="../public/javascript/Login.js"></script>
    </head onload = "onPageLoad()">
    <body>
        <center><h1>Login Page</h1></center>
        <center><img src="../images/Spotify_logo.png" width="1000" height="300"></center>
        <div>
            <center>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="clientId" class="form-label">Client ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientId" placeholder="">
                </div><br></br>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="clientSecret" class="form-label">Client Secret</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientSecret" placeholder="">
                </div><br></br>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" onclick="requestAuthorization()" value="Request Authorization"><br/>
            </div>
            </center>
        </div>
        <center><p>This website is intended only for Spotify Users. To create an account click <a href="https://www.spotify.com/ca-en/premium/?utm_source=ca-en_brand_contextual_text&utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_campaign=alwayson_ucanz_ca_premiumbusiness_highsubintent_brand+contextual+text+exact+ca-en+google&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlfr68Me7_gIVBymzAB2VLweoEAAYASAAEgLQuvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds">here</a></p></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login.js

```
const redirectLink = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'

let client_id = '';
let client_secret = '';

const AUTHORIZE = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

function requestAuthorization(){
    client_id = document.getElementById('clientId').value;
    client_secret = document.getElementById('clientSecret').value;
    localStorage.setItem('client_id', client_id);
    localStorage.setItem('client_secret', client_secret);
    console.log(client_id);
    let url = AUTHORIZE;
    url+='?client_id='+client_id;
    url+='&response_type=code';
    url += "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirectLink);
    url += "&show_dialog=true";
    url += "&scope=user-read-private user-read-email user-modify-playback-state user-read-playback-position user-library-read streaming user-read-playback-state user-read-recently-played playlist-read-private";
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = require('./router/htmlRoutes');
const path = require('path')
// const http = require('http');
// const fs = require('fs');


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const publicPath = '../client/src/public';
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, publicPath)));
// app.use(express.static('public/styles'));
// Use the router module
app.use('/', router);

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

My Project Structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── client
│   └── src
│       ├── pages
│       │   ├── createPlaylistPage.html
│       │   ├── homePage.html
│       │   ├── loginPage.html
│       │   ├── myPlaylistsPage.html
│       │   ├── recommendationPage.html
│       │   ├── searchPage.html
│       │   ├── suggestionsPage.html
│       │   ├── topArtistPage.html
│       │   └── topSongsPage.html
│       └── public
│           ├── images
│           │   └── Spotify_logo.png
│           ├── javascript
│           │   └── Login.js
│           └── styles
│               ├── createPlaylistPage.css
│               ├── global.css
│               ├── homePage.css
│               ├── loginPage.css
│               ├── myPlaylistPage.css
│               ├── recommendationPage.css
│               ├── searchPage.css
│               ├── suggestionsPage.css
│               └── topSongsPage.css
├── file-structure.txt
└── server
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── router
    │   └── htmlRoutes.js
    └── server.js
```

I tried looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040993/the-resource-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-text-html-mismatch-x-content-type) and it mostly says to check the link to script file. I have asked chatGPT to check my link looks good. Secondly, the link says to make sure the file is inside a public folder. I would be appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the html file in question is loginPage.html- or at least in the same folder as that.  If that is the case, you've put an extra ../ in your relative path in the script tag:

```html
<script src="../public/javascript/Login.js"></script>
// vs
<script src="../../public/javascript/Login.js"></script>
```

Comment: I should’ve mentioned this in question I have tried both apologies for that

Comment: I have edited my question to show the correct path

Comment: Understood.

Alright, what we know, is that the .js is not being imported. The error talks about a MIME type mismatch. Type on a script tag is an optional attribute, and it's generally suggested that you omit it (just as you have done). Is it possible that you have a config file (web.config, maybe), which is setting a default (and incorrect) MIME type?

Alternatively, you can try setting:
<script src="../public/javascript/Login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to figure out the error ```server.js``` file required ```app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, pagesPath)));```.